# Using Sleep() while using timers through setitimer

Tags: c++, unix, timer, sleep

I am using a timer in my C++ code through setitimer function from sys/time.h. This maps the SIGALRM signal to my timer handler method. After this I am not able to use sleep function. I am assuming it is because sleep uses SIGALRM signal as well. Can you suggest any workaround for this problem?

Thanks for replying.

Comment: +1 I'm sure I'll run into this problem myself sooner or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) just as a timer.  I don't know if it uses SIGALRM or not but it should be simple to test.  Something like:

```
   timeval t = {1, 0};

   select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &t);
```

Comment: ACE uses select to implement the timer, so I guess your suggestion should work.

Answer (score 8):

From the `alarm(2)` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm):

> `sleep()` may be implemented using `SIGALRM`; mixing calls to `alarm()` and `sleep()` is a bad idea.

Some implementations don't use `SIGALRM`, find a machine like that and you're set.  Otherwise, you can try `nanosleep()`; it's implemented safely.  From the `nanosleep(2)` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep):

> Compared to `sleep(3)` and `usleep(3)`, `nanosleep()` has the advantage of not affecting any signals, it is standardized by POSIX, it provides higher timing resolution, and it allows to continue a sleep that has been interrupted by a signal more easily.

Comment: When I use nanosleep() along with setitimer(), the timer handler gets executed at different intervals on Asus Tinkeboard. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a library that gives an abstraction to these OS services. I use [ACE](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/Stable/ace/classes.html) library for timers and sleeps (`ACE_OS::sleep`, `ACE_Reactor::schedule_timeout`) and they work together without any problems. As far as I know ACE uses `select` for its timers. I guess [boost::thread::sleep](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.sleep) and [boost::asio::deadline_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer1.html) will accomplish the task successfully as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it is required that I not use any third party libraries.  I cannot use Boost or ACE :( .

Comment: Well, then I guess Carl just gave the definitive answer :) (running to his post to vote it up).